# Determine Time complexity of cannon's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement cannon's algorithm, but unable to calculate the time complexity exactly. I am facing difficulty in including communication cost in complexity.

```
{1}for all i=0:N — 1 
     Left circular shift row i by i, so that A [i,j] is assigned A[i,(j+i)mod N] 
{2}for all j =0 : N — 1 
     Upward circular shift column j by j, so that B(i,j) assigned B[(j+i) modN,j]
{3}for k = 1 : N 
    {4}for all i = 0 : N — 1 , {5}for all j = 0 : N — 1 
        C[i,j]= C[i,j] + A[i,j]*B[i,j] ;
     Left circular shift each row of A by 1, so A[i,j] is assigned A[i,(j+1)mod N]
     Upward circular shift each column of B by 1, so B[i,j] is assigned B[(i+1)modN,j]
```

according to me :
 N{1,2: since 1,2 loops can proceed in parallel}+ ( N * N * N ){3,4,5} = N+N<sup>3</sup>

but the [link](http://www.phy.ornl.gov/csep/la/node6.html) states complexity otherwise. I know that i have not included the communication cost in my calculation.
A simple explanation( with communication cost & memory space requirement) here would be very useful.

Comment: what N+N^3 means in time complexity? did you mean N^3

Comment: @AliAmiri : if {1}& {2} were sequential so i would have taken N+N , but the {1} loop and {2} loop can run in parallel(non sequential) so, total time in these loops is N. And 3,4,5  have 3 nested for loops so N^3

Comment: Your reference assumes distributed implementation in an NxN processor mesh, so that also the N^3 loop is parallelized.